# Remove last Character from Textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I want a button to remove the last character from a Textbox, like the left arrow button in Windows calculator

```
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: show me what you have already tired.

Comment: @Seabizkit - OP tried "`private void button15_Click`" above, but it must have not worked.

Comment: `textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Remove(textbox1.Text.Length - 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = txtSomething.Text;
    txtSomething.Text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sYourText = txtYourTextBox.Text;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sYourText)){
       sYourText = sYourText.substring(0, sYourText.Length -1);
           txtYourTextBox.Text = sYourText;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are no additional requirement, this is what you need

```
var text = "something"; //your TextBox.Text
if (text.Length > 0)
    text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
```